# I can not install pytorch with Anaconda just because I ran out of disk space the first time

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, pytorch

I cannot install pytorch 1.5.0. Firstly, I opened Anaconda Prompt and activated my venv as follows:

```
conda activate gym
```

After that, I wanted to install pytorch in gym, so I wrote:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

This is from pytorch official [website](https://pytorch.org/).

But I ran out of space in my hard disk so the installation ended with an error. I've cleaned some space and then ran that command again, but it said:

```
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename D:\Python\Anaconda\pkgs\pytorch-1.5.0-py3.8_cuda102_cudnn7_0\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\torch_cuda.dll.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
```

I have deleted the whole archive and rebooted my PC. The error persisted. I did these steps several times.
Then I thought to install it in another way. I deleted the archive again and I was sure that there was no package left called pytorch (the archive was under `pkgs` folder under Anaconda installation). So I went to Anaconda official [website](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch) where I found this command:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

I tried it and now it says:

```
InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive D:\\Python\\Anaconda\\pkgs\\pytorch-1.5.0-py3.8_cuda102_cudnn7_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFile size could not be restored')
```

The archive was deleted for sure from my disk.

I even updated all packages in Anaconda with `conda update -n gym --all` and tried these steps several times.

All these problems just because I ran out of disk space? ...

I do not know what to do. Can you please help me? Thanks a lot for any answer! I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you ran out of space, can you move a bunch of things into a memory chip?

Comment: I've done that, I said in my question :) after I said about pytorch official website

Comment: I know, but maybe it wasn't enough, hence the 'bunch' and 'memory chip'.

Comment: The archive, while it was downloading, it showed almost 600MB. I cleaned up to 3GB. I don't think that is the problem

Comment: The extracted archive can be bigger than 3GB. Try deleting the contents of `~/.cache` folder to reclaim some space. You could do `conda clean --all` to remove unused cache packages.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I cleaned up to 5GB and it worked. I'm sorry, but I'm a beginner in Python packages. I downloaded some but they weren't that big as Pytorch was. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch just needed more than 3GB space to be downloaded. It's a big package! :) Thanks for helping me out in the comments!